# Changing layout of different tabs

Tags: android

I am using a tabbed activity with viewpager in android studio. I am trying to figure out how to change the layout on each tab. Can anyone help?

Comment: Post your code pls.

Answer (score 0):

there is a good example of use viewpager with some fragments in one activity, it's an open source project so you can guide by this. [soundRecorder](https://github.com/dkim0419/SoundRecorder)

pd: [MainActivity](https://github.com/dkim0419/SoundRecorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/danielkim/soundrecorder/activities/MainActivity.java)

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a different layout for each tab you can have it by defining your tablayout in XML.
Inside your root layout say for eg a RelativeLayout define the tablayout as follows

```
< android.support.design.widget.TabLayout  
    android: id="
    android:layout_width=
    android:layout_height=
    android:tabMode="scrollable">

    < android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout="@layout/my_tablayout_00">
    < android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout="@layout/my_tablayout_01">
```

Complete the XML file.

You can have as many tabs (TabItems) as you want. You can have separate layout files for each tab or you can have a few like 5 or 6 layout files and repeatedly give the same layouts to the tabs.

TabItems have only 3 XML attributes - icon, layout, and text.
In the layout file you can add some more features. That is commonly known.

I am using this and it is working fine.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

working with tabs well i don't know about the Tabbed Activity but working with `TabLayout`i batter option here is the reference [Android Material Design working with Tabs](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)